# "mit einem nassen Lappen erschlagen"

Tags: german-to-english

What is the meaning of this idiom?  "mit einem nassen Lappen erschlagen"

Comment: Seems to originate from producing sounds in theatre http://www.deutschlandfunkkultur.de/mein-lieber-scholli.1306.de.html?dram:article_id=193507

Comment: What did the dictionary tell you, and why is that not sufficient?

Comment: You should indicate the context where you found this. Meaning depens on context, here as always.

Comment: It's from a novel by Erich Kaestner, "Punktchen und Anton."  It appears to be a derogatory comment about an unpleasant woman.  I assume it's idiomatic as the literal translation, "one should kill her with a wet rag" makes no sense.

Comment: @bluerider Please edit your question to provide context. Do not add comments. Please take the tour of the site.

Comment: In Österreich wird man mit einem nassen Fetzen erschlagen wenn man »Lappen« sagt.

Answer (score 2):

"mit einem nassen Lappen erschlagen" (literally: "to beat someone to death qith a wet rag") is a common idiomatic expression (*possibly* only in Lower Saxony?) to express you would like to get rid of something or someone due to the thing or person being particularly annoying or unbearable. It is not a literal expression of intent, just an expression to underline how annoyed the speaker is.

Examples may depend very much on personal preferences; the proclaimed target might be e.g. (thinking of tv characters) a constantly grinning salesman, a permanently intrusive and obnoxious mother in law, or a wannabe gangster guy who constantly downplays his previous misbehaviour. For all of these, a fitting comment could be: "Die/Den könnte ich mit einem nassen Lappen erschlagen!"

I'll try and find some exemplary citations later on.

Comment: *»possibly only in Lower Saxony?«* This idiom is very well know in Austria, with one important difference: You have to replace *Lappen* by *Fetzen* (*jemanden mit einem nassen Fetzen erschlagen*). The word *Lappen* is not used in Austria, you use the synonym *Fetzen* instead.

Comment: (cont.) Originally a *Fetzen* was a worn out peace of clothing, that you use as cleaning cloth, but today any textiles that are used as cleaning rag are called *Fetzen* in Austria. A *Lappen* is a rectangular piece of textile, that was explicitly produced as cleaning rag. (A shabby old t-shirt is a *Fetzen* but not a *Lappen*. A brand new cleaning rag, that buy in a store, is both: *Fetzen* and *Lappen*)

Answer (score 0):

It means "to be beaten to death by a wet rag".
I do not know your text, but is it referring to insects?

Comment: Err, "with a wet rag", not "by a wet rag". That would be "von einem nassen Lappen".